# Java: Where to put code for file handling in larger project practice

Tags: java, oop, exception

Suppose the user selects a file path, in some gui handling class.
Thus, I receive a String with a file path.

Now, what is the best practice to put the file open/close code?
Should the path be converted to a InputStream object in the GUI class,
and then pass this object to the parser classes, or is it better
to pass the String object, and let the parser class handle file open/close operations?

I have preferred the second option, since it seems convenient to have the file handling and error handling in the same class, and then I pass null, or throw an Exception if there is any kind of failure. GUI handling code is verbose as it is, and I'd like to separate GUI and user action code from the core logic.

However, the first option is good since I can catch file reading exceptions earlier,
thus eliminate the need to "jump down" a class, only to throw an exception there.

What is a good practice on this? I believe there are more situations like this,
where objects are passed around a bit before being processed. 
Should error processing be made in the "higher-level" classes, or "low-level" core classes?

**Basically, should I convert from String to InputStream soon, or late?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No file processing should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread in the first place. This thread should only execute the minimum code needed to receive events, drive the GUI, and dispatch other concerns to separate threads. Otherwise you will be painting yourself into a corner called *sluggish GUI*, leading to poor user experience with your application.

Regarding the separation of concerns between a parser and file handling code, most commonly an API will have more value if it sticks to its core business, meaning it can be reused in the face of changing concerns not related to it.

Comment: Oh, right, I have used that a bit, but the question remains the same: "should I convert from String path to InputStream" as soon, or as late as possible?

Comment: My answer should be covering that as well because turning a String into an InputStream is already non-GUI processing. Handling exceptions and making the GUI react to them must be done through a well-established mechanism that works the same for both early and late-occurring exceptions.

Comment: Suppose the gui invokes a separate thread. Now, should THIS class open the file and pass inputstream to input processing class, or should this separate thread pass the path String?

Comment: So your question is not about GUI at all, but about the separation of concerns between a parser and file-handling code. Most commonly an API will have more value if it sticks to its core business, meaning it can be reused in the face of changing concerns not related to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try solving this with commands.

[Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Basically what you describe is a "Open file" Command.